# Correctly translate a scaled container in html/css

Tags: html, css, transform

So at first I set the blue container's height and width to `25px` and to translate it to the top right corner of the green container I simply translate x to `100-25=75px` and it works fine,

```html
<div id="app" style="margin: 20px">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: red;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      background-color: blue;
      transform-origin: center center;
      transform: translateX(75px);
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to achieve the same with scale.  I set height and width of blue container to `40px` and I scale it to `0.625` which basically sets the height and width of blue container to `25px` like above. However now when I want to translate it I can't translate with the above value i.e. `75px`. I tried putting the blue container back to top left and again tried translating to `75px` but it still doesn't work,

```html
<div id="app" style="margin: 20px">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: red;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      transform-origin: center center;
      transform: scale(0.625) translateX(-15px) translateY(-15px)
        translateX(75px);
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate then scale and set the origin to be `top right`

```html
<div id="app" style="margin: 20px">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: red;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      transform-origin: top right;
      transform:translate(60px) scale(0.625);
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

Or like below (`96 = 60/0.625`)

```html
<div id="app" style="margin: 20px">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: red;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      transform-origin: top right;
      transform:scale(0.625) translate(96px); 
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

without `transform-origin` (`30% = ((1-0.625)/2)/0.625) * 100%)`

```html
<div id="app" style="margin: 20px">
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: red;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    "
  ></div>
  <div
    style="
      position: absolute;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      background-color: blue;
      transform:translate(60px) scale(0.625) translate(30%,-30%);
    "
  ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don’t want to set origin to top right. I want to translate with it being in center.

Comment: @Damon and why? you are simply making things more complicated

Comment: The thing is I am using react native. React native doesn't have transform origin property.